# Mismatch of Points between QGIS and R loading with st_read()

Tags: qgis, r

I am working in QGIS version 3.30.0 in Windows 11 , and R Studio 2023.09.1

I have two gpkg files, one with polygons (called Segments) and one with points (which are charging stations) in the following Github Repository: https://github.com/AlejandraPP/California-Charging-Stations

The points file (Reprojected_CS_Segments.gpkg) contains one column in its attribute table called Segment, which indicates under which Segment every station falls under. When selecting all stations within Segment 10_1000_17_24_24, in QGIS I see a total of 28 points, of which some include some Fast Charging stations (see column EV_DC_F).
[image] [image]*Here the problem*: when I load this in R...

```
CS         <- st_read(file.path(path_geo, "Reprojected_CS_Segments.gpkg"))
```

[image]

... and I filter by Segment 10_1000_17_24_24 in column Segment (which indicates the name given of each segment) ...
[image]

... and I do not see any Fast Charge stations.

Why does this happen?

My only guess is that those stations very close to the border (0.96m) are left out somehow when loading the file in R.

Comment: There are 8 points in your data with a "Segment" value = "10_1000_17_24_24". Can you explain exactly how you did "I filter by Segment 10_1000_17_24_24"? Is that by spatial intersection with a polygon from the other geopackage? Can you show the code? Or are you somehow using the "Filter" thing in what looks like RStudio?

Comment: HI Spacedman,

When I say "I filter by..." I mean that in R Studio, when I load the .gpkg file, I can filter (in my case, Segment) for Segment_10_1000_17_24_24 like I have edited in the post.

Comment: So in the QGIS screens, "selection" is done by intersecting points with the polygons? Not the "Segment" attribute value?

Comment: Correct. The selected (yellow) dots in the QGIS screenshot are selected by hand (Selection tool). All of them, although cannot be seen in the Attribute Table screenshot, have the same segment in their Segment column, which yes, was performed via an Intersection of (base layer) points and polygons (overlay layer).

I have been researching and it might be the CRS that I am using **EPSG:7755 - WGS 84 / India NSF LCC**. I used this one (probably rookie mistake) just because it was in meters.